# Fullpage.js: Leaving last slide to the right, jump to next section?

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I'm using the [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) plugin.

I have 5 sections underneath with each 10 slides horizontally.
I wonder how I can jump to the next section once I've reached the 10th slide of the section.

```
onSlideLeave: function( anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction) {
            if ( slideIndex === 10 ) { 
                //$.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
            }
        }
```

So again, when I'm scrolling horizontally through my slides and I reach the last one, I want to jump to the first on the next section.

Kind Regards,
Sepp88

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in the [plugin documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#onslideleave-anchorlink-index-slideindex-direction):

> slideIndex: index of the slide. **Starting from 0.**

Try this instead:

```
onSlideLeave: function (anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction) {
    if (slideIndex === 9) {
        $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
    }
}
```